# Calculating the circulation field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Gretings fellow mathematicians!

I'm learning multivariable calculus and i seem to be stuck in a problem which i cannot even manage to construct the intuition behind it, the problem is the following:

Using Green's theorem calculate the circulation field of $F=(x+y)i+(2y-x^2)j$ around $4x^2+y^2=4$ circled once counter clockwise.

I know it is a very newbie question but im still starting this course, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are plenty of resources online where you can find examples of similar problems. See for example http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GreensTheorem.aspx. If you cannot work it out based on these examples, you could tell us where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be a parametrization of the curve. The integral of $F$ along $\gamma$ is by definition (in differential form notation) $$\int_\gamma (x+y)dx + (2y-x^2)dy.$$ Green's theorem states that this is equal to $$\iint_E \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2y-x^2) - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x+y)\right] dxdy$$ Where $E$ is the area enclosed in the ellipse. Just compute this integral and you're done. The intuition i have for this value is that it's simply a measure of how much the curve "follows" the vector field (in fact it is $0$ when they're orthogonal, positive when they have the same orientation and negative when they have opposite orientations). Maybe try to plot the field and guess the sign before actually computing the integral to see if you get it.